# Output code into a string

Tags: php

I want to get the output of the following code into a string in PHP.

```
if( Is_Array( $Players ) ){
   foreach( $Players as $Player ) {
      echo "<tr>";echo "<td>";
      echo htmlspecialchars( $Player[ 'Name' ] );
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo htmlspecialchars( $Player[ 'TimeF' ] );
      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
} else {
   echo "<tr><td colspan='2' >No players in da house!</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Use concatenation instead of `echo`

Comment: I want to get the output of the code above into a string. When I use ther following code, I get an "unexpected T_IF, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\qc\source\server.php" error.
 
CODE: $players = if( Is_Array( $Players ) ){
   foreach( $Players as $Player ) {
      echo "<tr>";echo "<td>";
      echo htmlspecialchars( $Player[ 'Name' ] );
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo htmlspecialchars( $Player[ 'TimeF' ] );
      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
} else {
   echo "<tr><td colspan='2' >No players in da house!</td></tr>";
}

Answer (score 1):

Swap out all of your instances of `echo` with `$string.=`

Comment: I don't think I need to show you what your code would look like.  It's really simple: look at your code.  Every place that says `echo`, replace it with `$string.=` The echo'd out content will now instead be in `$string`.  It's not rocket science... If you are getting an error, it is not from this.

Comment: that was a response to a comment OP made, saying something along the lines of "I tried this and still got an error, please post the code?" which he deleted.

Comment: Yeah, it overwrites the previous string and only outputs the last.

Comment: okay well it sounds like you aren't putting the dot between `$string` and `=`.  Notice there's a dot in my code